# im learning react.js..i keep getting this error Unexpected token, expected ",".what's the mistake in my jsx?

Tags: reactjs

Unexpected token, expected ",".what's the mistake in my jsx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <div className="logs-container">
    {logContext.logs.length === 0 || logContext.loading === true ? (
      <h1>loading....</h1>
    ) : (
      logContext.logs.map((singleLog) => (
        <LogItem key={singleLog._id} log={singleLog} />
      ))
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Umm...where did this come from?

Comment: From the code you included before you edited it out?..